# Generic type with parameter type restriction cannot be passed to method with non-generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics

Type variance makes my head hurt. I was under the impression that the `out` variance modifier on `IEnumerable<out T>` should allow this behavior.

```
interface ISampleInterface
{

}

/// <summary>
/// This works great!
/// </summary>
static void GenericMethod<TSeq>(TSeq sequence) where TSeq : IEnumerable<ISampleInterface>
{
    UseInterface(sequence);
}

/// <summary>
/// This does not compile :(
/// </summary>
static void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : ISampleInterface
{
    UseInterface(sequence);
}

static void UseInterface(IEnumerable<ISampleInterface> item)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

The error is;

> Error    CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>` to `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ISampleInterface>`

Why does `GenericMethod<T>` fail to compile, but `GenericMethod<TSeq>` compiles just fine?

Comment: `static void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : class, ISampleInterface`

Comment: @canton7 That certainly makes the error go away, but why does it work?

Comment: Why the `foreach()` though?

Comment: @CodeCaster that is an irrelevant part of the code I extracted this example from. I shall remove it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that variance (e.g. `IEnumerable<out T>`) only applies to *reference* conversions. You can't do:

```
IEnumerable<object> x = new List<int>(); // Boxing conversion
IEnumerable<long> x = new List<int>();   // User-defined type conversion
```

(This intuitively makes sense: the code using `x` doesn't know that the underlying collection is of a different type, so there's no way for it to insert the code to box each `int`, or convert each `int` to a `long`.)

In:

```
static void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : ISampleInterface
{
    UseInterface(sequence);
}
```

The compiler does know that `T` has to implement `ISampleInterface`, but that doesn't stop you from defining:

```
public struct Foo : ISampleInterface { }
```

and passing that. Because there's no reference conversion from `Foo` to `ISampleInterface`, covariance isn't allowed.

If you tell the compiler that `T` must additionally be a reference type, by doing:

```
static void GenericMethod<T>(IEnumerable<T> sequence) where T : class, ISampleInterface
```

then the compiler can be sure that there *is* a reference conversion from `T` to `ISampleInterface`, and it compiles.